# Keras CNN with low/constant accuracies

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, tensorflow, keras

I am dealing with the Street View House Number recognition problem. I am trying to train a CNN with Keras.

Here is how I prepared the input:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFilter
train_folders = 'sv_train/train'
test_folders = 'test'
extra_folders = 'extra'
SV_IMG_SIZE = 28
SV_CHANNELS = 1
train_imsize = np.ndarray([len(train_data),2])
k = 500
sv_images = []
max_images = 20000#len(train_data)
max_digits = 5
sv_labels = np.ones([max_images, max_digits], dtype=int) * 10 # init to 10 cause it would be no digit
nboxes = [[] for i in range(max_images)]
print ("%d to load" % len(train_data))
def getBBox(i,perc):
    '''
    Given i, the desired i.png, returns
    x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max,
    the four numbers which define the small rectangular bounding
    box that contains all individual character bounding boxes
    '''
    boxes = train_data[i]['boxes'] 
    x_min=9990
    y_min=9990
    x_max=0
    y_max=0
    for bid,b in enumerate(boxes):
        x_min = b['left'] if b['left'] <= x_min else x_min
        y_min = b['top'] if b['top'] <= y_min else y_min
        x_max = b['left']+b['width'] if  b['left']+b['width'] >= x_max else x_max
        y_max = b['top']+b['height'] if b['top']+b['height'] >= y_max else y_max

    dy = y_max-y_min
    dx = x_max-x_min
    dpy = dy*perc
    dpx = dx*perc
    nboxes[i]=[dpx,dpy,dx,dy]
    return x_min-dpx, y_min-dpy, x_max+dpx, y_max+dpy

for i in range(max_images):
    print (" \r%d" % i ,end="")
    filename = train_data[i]['filename']
    fullname = os.path.join(train_folders, filename)
    boxes = train_data[i]['boxes']
    label = [10,10,10,10,10]
    lb = len(boxes)
    if lb <= max_digits:
        im = Image.open(fullname)
        x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max = getBBox(i,0.3)
        im = im.crop([x_min,y_min,x_max,y_max])
        owidth, oheight = im.size
        wr = SV_IMG_SIZE/float(owidth)
        hr = SV_IMG_SIZE/float(oheight)
        for bid,box in  enumerate(boxes):
            sv_labels[i][max_digits-lb+bid] = int(box['label'])

        box = nboxes[i]
        box[0]*=wr
        box[1]*=wr
        box[2]*=hr
        box[3]*=hr
        im = im.resize((SV_IMG_SIZE,SV_IMG_SIZE),Image.ANTIALIAS)
        img = img - np.mean(img)
        im = im.filter(ImageFilter.EDGE_ENHANCE)
        img = img - np.mean(img)

        array = np.asarray(im)
        array =  array.reshape((SV_IMG_SIZE,SV_IMG_SIZE,3)).astype(np.float32)
        na = np.zeros([SV_IMG_SIZE,SV_IMG_SIZE],dtype=int)
        for x in range (array.shape[0]):
            for y in range (array.shape[1]):
                na[x][y]=np.average(array[x][y][:])
        na = na.reshape(SV_IMG_SIZE,SV_IMG_SIZE,1)
        #print(array.shape)
        sv_images.append(na.astype(np.float32))

sv_train, sv_validation, svt_labels, svv_labels = train_test_split(sv_images, sv_labels, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

And here is how I created and trained the model:

```
model = Sequential()
x = Input((28, 28,1))

y = Convolution2D(16, 3, 3, border_mode="same")(x)
#y = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides = (2, 2)) (y)
#y = Dropout(0.25)(y)

y = Convolution2D(32, 4, 4, border_mode="same")(y)
y = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (3, 3)) (y)
#y = Dropout(0.25)(y)

y = Convolution2D(64, 5, 5, border_mode="same", activation="relu")(y)
y = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(y)
#y = Dropout(0.25)(y)

y = Convolution2D(128, 5, 5, border_mode="same", activation="relu")(y)
y = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(y)
#y = Dropout(0.25)(y)


y = Flatten()(y)
y = Dense(1024, activation="relu")(y)

digit1 = Dense(11, activation="softmax")(y)
digit2 = Dense(11, activation="softmax")(y)
digit3 = Dense(11, activation="softmax")(y)
digit4 = Dense(11, activation="softmax")(y)
digit5 = Dense(11, activation="softmax")(y)
model = Model(input=x, output=[digit1, digit2, digit3,digit4,digit5])


model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.layers[0].output_shape)
print(model.layers[2].output_shape)
print(model.layers[4].output_shape)
print(model.layers[6].output_shape)
print(model.layers[8].output_shape)

sv_train_labels = [svt_labels[:,0],svt_labels[:,1],svt_labels[:,2],svt_labels[:,3],svt_labels[:,4]]
sv_validation_labels = [svv_labels[:,0],svv_labels[:,1],svv_labels[:,2],svv_labels[:,3],svv_labels[:,4]]

model.fit(sv_train, sv_train_labels, nb_epoch=10, batch_size=64,validation_data=(sv_validation, sv_validation_labels))
```

The problem is that I get very low accuracies that remain with the same value at each epoch:

```
Train on 13400 samples, validate on 6600 samples
Epoch 1/10
13400/13400 [==============================] - 78s - loss: 34.7407 - dense_740_loss: 0.1161 - dense_741_loss: 0.6879 - dense_742_loss: 4.7988 - dense_743_loss: 14.7893 - dense_744_loss: 14.3486 - dense_740_acc: 0.9902 - dense_741_acc: 0.9542 - dense_742_acc: 0.7001 - dense_743_acc: 0.0810 - dense_744_acc: 0.1055 - val_loss: 34.7760 - val_dense_740_loss: 0.0049 - val_dense_741_loss: 0.7131 - val_dense_742_loss: 4.8721 - val_dense_743_loss: 14.8091 - val_dense_744_loss: 14.3769 - val_dense_740_acc: 0.9997 - val_dense_741_acc: 0.9558 - val_dense_742_acc: 0.6977 - val_dense_743_acc: 0.0812 - val_dense_744_acc: 0.1080
Epoch 2/10
13400/13400 [==============================] - 70s - loss: 34.7032 - dense_740_loss: 0.0036 - dense_741_loss: 0.6760 - dense_742_loss: 4.7861 - dense_743_loss: 14.8118 - dense_744_loss: 14.4257 - dense_740_acc: 0.9998 - dense_741_acc: 0.9581 - dense_742_acc: 0.7031 - dense_743_acc: 0.0810 - dense_744_acc: 0.1050 - val_loss: 34.7760 - val_dense_740_loss: 0.0049 - val_dense_741_loss: 0.7131 - val_dense_742_loss: 4.8721 - val_dense_743_loss: 14.8091 - val_dense_744_loss: 14.3769 - val_dense_740_acc: 0.9997 - val_dense_741_acc: 0.9558 - val_dense_742_acc: 0.6977 - val_dense_743_acc: 0.0812 - val_dense_744_acc: 0.1080
```

Comment: How many epoches did you run in total?

Comment: 10 epches. too few?

Answer (score 2):

As I don't have your data, I can only give you some suggestions.

1. 10 epoches may be too few. In my practice, 100+ epoches will be applied. I think 100 epoches will be a good start for you.
2. Assuming your data is fully-prepared, some suggestions of the CNN:

   1. The first and the second convolution layers should have ReLU activations, at least not linear activations.
   2. Why do your output layer have 11 neurons? There are only 10 digits, right?
   3. `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` is used for sparse input. Your `sv_train_labels` seems to be a non-sparse array, thus `categorical_crossentropy` is better.
   4. Your 3x3, 4x4, 5x5 convolution layer seems weird, but I can't give you a reason (maybe someone else?). If I were you, I would use 3x3 layer.
   5. If you want to print your output shape of your model, try `model.summary()`. It's awesome!
   6. If I were you, I'll try `RMSprop` rather than `Adam`.

My model if you wanna try:

```
x = Input((28, 28, 1))

y = Convolution2D(16, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(x)
y = Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(y)
y = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(y)
y = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(y)
y = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(y)
y = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(y)
y = Flatten()(y)
y = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(y)

digit1 = Dense(10, activation="softmax")(y)
digit2 = Dense(10, activation="softmax")(y)
digit3 = Dense(10, activation="softmax")(y)
digit4 = Dense(10, activation="softmax")(y)
digit5 = Dense(10, activation="softmax")(y)
model = Model(input=x, output=[digit1, digit2, digit3, digit4, digit5])

model.compile('RMSprop', 'categorical_crossentropy', ['accuracy'])
```